# Crystal Reports and SQL Server many-to-many reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, many-to-many

This might be a simple question - I have a particular data setup on my SQL Server database whereby many customers can use many banks. One customer can have many bank branches, in turn, those branches may well be used by many other customers.

In addition, I have a third table for the status the customer, which is also many to many. I think this is where things are starting to go astray. The idea is to create an overall view of customers, their bank(s) and their status. However, where a customer has more than one bank, obviously there are repeated rows in a view result set, such as Smith below:

```
CustomerName | BankName | BankCity   | Status
----------------------------------------------
Smith        | Lloyds   | Manchester | Live
Smith        | Barclays | Rochdale   | Live
Jones        | Lloyds   | Manchester | Live    
Brown        | NatWest  | Oldham     | Cold
White        | Barclays | Oldham     | Live
```

I want to use Crystal Reports to run a datasheet which might look something like:

```
Customer: Smith
Banks: Lloyds, Manchester
       Barclays, Rochdale
Status:Live

Customer: Jones
Banks: Lloyds, Manchester
Status:Live
```

Is it easier to prepare this in Crystal Reports from the source data tables, or create an alternative view in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MS SQL

Comment: To get the ouput looking like your desired output - it should be done in Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in crystal reports:

1. Group by customer and place customer name in `group header`
2. Place Bank name , Bank City in details
3. Status in Group Footer